# JQuery document.ready function not being fired

Tags: jquery

Nothing complicated, really, it's just that this code doesn't seem to fire because the text on the "#title" div doesn't change

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = $('#cofzSlider img');
    var count = images.length();
    var i = 0;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (i == count) {
            i = 0;
        }
        i++;
        images[i].addClass('active');
        $('#title').text("dasdas");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `length` isn't a function, it's a property; use `var count = images.length` instead.

Comment: Did you even check the console?

Comment: Why are you executing `$('#cofzSlider img')` before page load?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the asker didn't even attempt to debug

Comment: When there's a code error does the code after the error get executed or does the debugging stop?

Comment: If an exception is thrown, the execution doesn't continue

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple problems.

`length` is a property, not a function. Should be:

```
var count = images.length;
```

`addClass` is a jquery function, not for the element. Should be like this to get the jquery object rather than the dom element:

```
    images.eq(i).addClass('active');
```

It appears that you will be getting `images[1]` every time the page is loaded based on what you have, is this desired?

As you are accessing the dom with `$('#cofzSlider img');`, you'll want to make sure that is also within your `$(document).ready()`

PS: You should see some of these errors if you just look at the console when you run it. You should try to do that before asking questions here to avoid this.

Comment: [Jan's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432284/jquery-document-ready-function-not-being-fired#comment25320791_17432284) will likely be relevant as well.

Comment: Yes , the problem seems to be that i don't know how to access an object in an array and also i tried to access the array before the document loaded . Thanks , this comment fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

you have multiple problems:

1. Length is a property, it isn't a function.
   change `var count = images.length();` to `var count = images.length;`
2. You are incrementing `i` before you use it which means you'll never get the 0th element in `images` so move `i++` to the end.
3. Why do you even have a `i++` in a function that is only called once? This doesn't make much sense to me. Maybe I'm just not seeing it. If you want to set all images to active just do: `images.addClass('active');`